# HTTP Method to use for adding to a collection in a RESTful API

Tags: api, rest, http-method

I have a resource that represents a collection of tags:

```
/users/{username}/tags
```

An API client should be able to add a set of tags to this collection in a single HTTP request.  I thought about how to do this and first thought about using the PUT or POST methods. However I think this would imply that the client is "setting" or "replacing" the tags in that collection. What would be the most appropriate HTTP method (or perhaps a different mechanism) to "add" multiple tags to that collection?

```
{HTTP METHOD} /users/{username}/tags
```

Request Body:

```
 ["short", "crazy", "funny"]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the tags being sent in the request body are intended to be added to a collection, rather than replace, I would suggest POST. If you intend to replace the existing tags, use PUT.

Answer (score 13):

`PUT /users/alganet/tags` replaces all the tags.

`POST /users/alganet/tags` adds more tags.

You can also use [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789).

`PATCH /users/alganet/tags` changes tags.

Possible body:

`{"POST":["rest", "php"], "DELETE":["soap"]}`

The body must have a specific patch format matching the `Accept-Patch` header. The sample body above is a custom format for patches, but you could use a clean `diff` for example.