# Can REST API PATCH responses with different resource that should be applied to confirm the patch?

Tags: rest, server, api-design

I'm working on a server developing REST API.

The structure by now (at least what is needed to know for this question) is that I have a products collection retrievable via `GET /products`, `GET /products/:id`. I want to be able to edit these products, but I want to be able also to make drafts. This will be useful for save the edits but apply them only when done and make a history of the edits.

I thought that a possible way could be develop this endpoints:

```
GET /products/:id/drafts
 this will retrieve all the drafts made for this product

GET /products/:id/draft
 this will retrieve the last non applied draft, if any

POST /products/:id/draft/apply
 this will apply the last non applied draft, if any
```

To this point, all seems fine, but I am struggling finding a good way for handling the creation of the drafts. I thought that it could be `POST /products/:id/drafts` but, because of there can be only one draft a time, should this response with `409 Conflict` if is there any non applied draft yet?

So I thought that it could be `PATCH /products/:id`, so if there is yet a non applied draft, then it will be edited else it will be created. Could it be done?

Can the `PATCH /products/:id` return a representation of the draft (created or edited)?

Is it better the `POST` approach described before?

Is there another way that I can't think of?

Comment: "_...but should this response with 409 Conflict if is there any non applied draft yet?_"  It should append a new draft to the collection and respond with an ID for that draft.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855388/http-method-to-use-for-adding-to-a-collection-in-a-restful-api

Comment: Sorry I didn't say that there can be only one draft a time

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to change the semantics of [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789), which is not a good idea.

HTTP includes methods that support remote authoring use cases; for instance, if I wanted to change the title of the home page on my web site, the sequence of steps might look like

```
GET /home.html
```

```
200 OK
Content-Type: text/html

<html>...
```

(make local changes)

```
PUT /home.html
Content-Type: text/html

<html>...
```

```
200 OK
```

Now, if `home.html` were very big (relative to the size of the standard HTTP headers) and the changes we were making were very small, then we might instead want to send a *patch document* instead of sending the entire mostly unchanged file.

```
PATCH /home.html
Content-Type: text/prs.patch

????
```

```
200 OK
```

If we wanted to create a draft, using the general purpose remote authoring interface, then our sequence of requests would look something like

```
GET /documents/123
PUT /drafts/456
```

and publish would look something like

```
GET /drafts/456
PUT /documents/123
```

What it sounds like you want is to achieve this without sending the documents over the wire, allowing the server to manage the process.  The usual way to do that is with [POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)

> POST serves many useful purposes in HTTP, including the general purpose of “this action isn’t worth standardizing.”

```
POST /documents/123

???
```

```
201 Created
Location: /drafts/456
```

```
POST /drafts/456

???
```

```
200 OK
```

The server would use the payload of the POST requests to resolve any ambiguity that might be introduced by having multiple "not worth standardizing" actions.

Comment: Thank you. I written `/products/:id/drafts` because I want to keep the drafts collection linked to the product resource. If I understood what you are saying, I could use `POST /products/:id/drafts` to create a new draft or edit the last non applied one and in the header include the location to that draft resource. Then use all the other endpoints as I described in the question. Should this work so?